# Emulate joystick input via numeric input

Tags: arch-linux, x11, arduino, joystick

I have an arduino which gives me numbers from a potentiometer (300-600), device /dev/ttyACM0 baudrate 9600.

I want to use these numbers as a 1-axis joystick.

My system is archlinux and X-Displaymanager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done it with python and uinput:

```
#!/bin/env python2

import serial
import time
import uinput
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
events = (uinput.BTN_JOYSTICK, uinput.ABS_X + (0, 255, 0, 0))
device = uinput.Device(events)
device.emit(uinput.ABS_X, 128, syn=False)
while True:
    value = ser.readline()
    valuecorrect = value.strip()
    valuecorrect = int(valuecorrect)/4
    print valuecorrect
    device.emit(uinput.ABS_X, int(valuecorrect))
```

For the calibration I use jstest-gtk.